# Sumif for dynamic range of columns

Tags: excel, indexing, match, sumifs

Hi I have store numbers in different columns and products in rows with sales for respective stores. I want to do sumif in a different sheet by changing stores and products in data validated cells. How do I select dynamic columns in Sumif based on store numbers. Attaching image for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a mockup based on your sample data, with row numbers and column letters shown:

[image]

Using that as a base, in cell C15 is this formula:

```
=SUMIF($C$3:$C$9,$C$14,INDEX($D$3:$G$9,0,MATCH($C$13,$D$2:$G$2,0)))
```

You'll need to adjust the ranges to suit your actual data.

Comment: Brilliant Thank you very Much :)

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUMIF(A2:A6,"=Shirts",B2:B6)
```

- `A2:A6` - This is the range over which the condition applies
- `"=Shirts"` - the conditional expression.
- `B2:B6` - The cells under consideration for summing up.

Comment: Store number is dynamic. If I change the store number I want the sum for the new store number (for eg:1202) with the same formula. So in your formula "B2:B6" should be changing automatically everytime I change the store number